# "Unable to start program" on F5 in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Fresh Windows 8 release build. Fresh VS 2012. Fresh new Project. No code changed. Hit F5 and get:

> Unable to start program 'http://localhost:2209/'.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Have admin rights. Running as admin, elevated.

Very shocked to see this on a clean install. Only other thing installed is Chrome. Using Process Monitor, I can see that IIS Express is all fine. The internal browser launches fine and site is shown. It's even published on Azure, so its building fine.

The only error in Procmon is "NAME NOT FOUND" on C:\DATA\Code\My.Solution.Folder\enc_temp_folder

I tried making this folder and interestingly, VS deletes it. I assume Procmon is seeing some clean-up action.

UPDATE 1

Added c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe to "Browse with..." programs and it doesn't add it a second time, so I added it with a fake switch, and the same error occurs. Adding the x86 iexplore.exe results in the debugger loading but no IE.

Added path to Chrome.exe and that works. Seems IE 10 is FUBAR out of the box.

UPDATE 2

Reinstalled IE 10 via Programs and Features but no luck.